# Change ConnectionString in run-time in App.config not saved until rebuild a program

Tags: c#, app-config

I'm using a WinForm form created with C # to connect to a Sql server database.

To connect to the database the user must provide a login and a password.

I use the configuration file App.config to store the connectionString as following :

```
 <ConnectionStrings>
         <Add name = "K1" connectionString = "Data Source = HP; Initial Catalog = TRVANALYT; User ID = {0}; Password = {1}
       ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </ ConnectionStrings>
```

The problem that is posed to me does not save a new `connectionString`.
to refresh connextionString K1 I must rebuild the program and it gives the right result
If you have suggestions
What's the best practice?
thank you very much

My Code :

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
string connexionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["K1"].ToString();
var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection) config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
string NewConnexionstring = string.Format(connexionstring, txtUser.Text, txtPwd.Text);
connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["K1"].ConnectionString = NewConnexionstring; //Set new connectionString with user and password
connectionStringsSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

App.config

```
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="K1" connectionString="Data Source=HP;Initial Catalog=TRVANALYT;User ID={0};Password={1}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: In what path are you editing your app.config file? The file is copied to the bin folder and renamed to YourApp.exe.config during build, and it is from there that the application actually reads it - so if you edit there, you shouldn't have to rebuild.

Comment: Why do I have to know the path?
The essentials I execute the program and I want to change app.config for the new user and his password for sql server
And how I proceed to do what you ask?

Comment: The reason I ask is that you say you must rebuild the program for changes to apply. When you build, the file is copied to the bin directory, which is where it is read when the program runs. If you edit your file in the source directory, the program will not see the changes until it is rebuilt and the files i copied to the bin folder again.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but when I debug, I realize that the ConnectionString was saved, but when I create a new object, the Connectionstring of this is false.
I fix that by this way:

- In the Entity.Context.cs file (In my case is  QuanLySieuThi.Context.cs) you will see a partial class. You should add a new constructor with a Connectionstring parameter in this class:

Code

```
 public partial class QuanLySieuThiEntities : DbContext
 {
     //This is the default constructor
     public QuanLySieuThiEntities()
         : base("name=QuanLySieuThiEntities")
     {
     }
     //Add this constructor
     public QuanLySieuThiEntities(String connString)
         : base(connString)
     {
     }
 }
```

- Last, when you init a new object, you should use the new constructor with the connectionstring you need:

Code

```
  string _conString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuanLySieuThiEntities"].ConnectionString;
  QuanLySieuThiEntities newObject = new QuanLySieuThiEntities(_conString);
```